# django-rest-swagger UI doesn't have form for POST request body (function based view)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-rest-swagger

I have this **function-based view** with django-rest-swagger decorated. However, I can't find place in UI that allow me to post the payload (request.body).

I saw a couple solutions about doing it with class-based view, but I was wondering if there is a way to do it with function-based view.

Thank you in advance!

```
@renderer_classes([JSONRender])
@api_view(['POST'])
def some_method(request):
    body = json.loads(request.body)
    return JsonResponse({'status': 'ok'})
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am gonna answer my question since the *django-rest-swagger* was **deprecated in June 2019** and I just found out 2 feasible solutions.

First one will change the UI **globally**.

In `ping.views` (or any other location you wish) add following class.

```
from rest_framework.schema import AutoSchema

class CustomSchema(AutoSchema):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomSchema, self).__init__()
    def get_manual_fields(self, path, method):
        extra_fields = [
            coreapi.Field('command', required=True, location='form', schema=String(), description='', type='', example='',
            coreapi.Field('params', required=False, location='form', schema=String(), description='', type='', example='',
        ]
        manual_fields = super().get_manual_fields(path, method)
        return manual_fields + extra_fields
```

Add following settings in `settings.py` of your Django project.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # Corresponding path to where you added the class
    'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS': 'ping.views.CustomSchema', 
}
```

Second solution can be applied on a **per-view basis**. You may check here for [official guide](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#view-schema-decorator)

Use @schema from `rest_framework.decorators.schema` to overwrite `DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS`.

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@schema(CustomSchema())
def your_view(request):
    print(request.body)
    return JsonResponse({'task_status': 200'})
```

---

Basically, the idea is to overwrite `DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS`. The word `schema` is the term that they used to refer to swagger UI for each view in `rest_framework`.

When you use `@api_view()` to decorate your function-based view, it will assign your function an attribute `schema` with value `APIView.schema` from `rest_framework.views.APIView`.

`rest_framework.views.APIView` will in further call `DefaultSchema()` to load the `DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS` from your `REST_FRAMEWORK` configuration in `settings.py`.

Without other specifying, `DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS` is `rest_framework.schemas.openapi.AutoSchema` by this [official announcement](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/3.10-announcement/). You might want to change it to `rest_framework.schemas.coreapi.AutoSchema` since it is the one that compatible with `django_rest_swagger`.

---

Hope this tutorial helps people who use `django-rest-swagger (2.2.0)` with ***function-based views*** for their Django project.

Please leave comments if there are anything I can help on this issue.